Neo4J JDBC Driver ConnectionReadTimeoutException
I'm using the JDBC Driver to connect to my AuraDB instance from Denodo. Intermittently but consistently an error will occur with the following error message:
Received exception with message 'org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ConnectionReadTimeoutException: Connection read timed out due to it taking longer than the server-supplied timeout value via configuration hint.' Received exception with message 'Connection read timed out due to it taking longer than the server-supplied timeout value via configuration hint.'
The error always happen after 60 seconds. I've modified the connection.timeout property to be 900000, but the error persists. Is there anything that can be modified to remove this timeout?

I think that the issue is related to the Neo4j driver rather than Denodo's connection settings. In this case, the property you should modify is not connection.timeout but connection.recv_timeout_seconds (from the driver). This property controls the timeout for receiving data from Neo4j, and if it’s not set properly, it can trigger the error you're encountering.
Here's a reference to the official documentation regarding the issue: Neo4j Driver ConnectionReadTimeoutException.
Try adjusting that property instead of connection.timeout and see if it resolves the issue.
